# Form Array Populate to Another Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using `reactive forms` and have Form Arrays Inside. One component stores the values into database and I have now another component for editing those values and update them.
but I cannot figure out for Form Arrays because I cannot fetch them to formarray fields. it says ForEach does not exist on {}. What could be wrong?
Here is my code.

**edit.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.requestID = this.route.snapshot.params.requestID;
    this.formService.getFormDetails(this.formID).subscribe((data: any) => {
          data.forEach(customer => {
            if (customer) {
              this.customerFormEdit.patchValue({
                requestID: customer.requestID,
                requestType: customer.requestInformation.requestType,
                specialRequest: customer.specialRequest,
                sendTo_email: customer.requestInformation.sendTo.email
    // I know patch values is used to patch normal fields
    });
this.getEquip()
}
 getEquip() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.customerFormEdit.controls['equipment'];
    this.customers.equipment.forEach(x => {
      control.push(this.fb.group({ SerialNo: x.serialNo }))
    })
  }
```

this is how my customers Model looks like

```
export class CustomerForm {
  company: string;
  attention: string;
  email: string;
  requestType: string;
  specialRequest:string
  equipment: {
    serialNo: string;
    customerID: string;
  };
}
```

and this how form array is stored in JSON

```
"installations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cb54f48c39990305c8e026e"),
            "customerSerialNo" : "273823",
            "customerID" : "32324",
}]
```

// fb Array

```
equipment:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
serialNo:"",
customerID:""
})])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared equipment as a Object inside the Model, whereas it should be an array.

Your Model should be separated as,

```
export class CustomerForm {
  company: string;
  attention: string;
  email: string;
  requestType: string;
  specialRequest:string
  equipment[];
}


export class equipment{
  serialNo: string;
  customerID: string;
}
```

Comment: I have tried `equipment:[{
serialNo: string;
customerID: string;
]};`
but then it says Cannot read property 'equipment' of undefined and Cannot find control with name: 'equipment'

Comment: you need to debu and see if the values are there

Comment: control values are empty : (

Comment: which means you need to fix that first

Comment: but I don't understand why is that empty?